# Will a UK ban affect other visa applications?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I was banned for a year in the UK and that ban has been passed and removed from the UK.

Will this have implication on any other visa that I apply to other countries?

Comment: What passport do you hold? Was the ban cancelled, or merely finished - for example a two year ban.

Comment: What sort of ... positive feedback? Have they totally removed all record of the ban, or has it just finished and you can now return?

Answer (score 4):

Some countries ask on the visa application form if you have ever been banned from *any* country. As far as I remember, the US asks this question. Because you have to tick "yes" now, this may make it harder to get a visa approved. Don't consider ticking "no", because the risk of them finding out is high - and this will surely get your visa denied.

As preparation, collect all documentation about your ban, in particular 1) a proof that the ban expired, and 2) the reason for the ban.

You may be asked for this information upon applying for some visa in the future and should have an explanation ready that will convince the officials of the country whose visa you are applying for that this will not happen again. If the reason for the ban was not so severe (e.g., if you have been banned for having handed in a tax declaration that was 1 pound off somewhere), they may still approve your visa.

Comment: Hence if the ban was not your fault, it should not affect other applications.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @DCTLib's answer, never lie on any visa application. So it isn't a consideration to say the truth, its your obligation. Especially since UK is a part of [Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) and finding out truth about what you mention in your visa application is a menial thing. So, although I do not know how a UK visa ban will affect other visa applications, not mentioning it when asked definitely will.

Comment: I tried applying to UK again but I got 10 year visa ban. They have given a silly reason. This is not my fault though, is it worth applying for admisntration review or just should I go for judicail review?